# If my attack roll equals the target's AC, is it hit or miss?

Tags: microlite20

Microlite20 core rules pdf says:

> Add attack bonus to d20 roll. If higher than your opponent's Armour Class (AC), it’s a hit.

Do I get it right — "if higher" means that if my attack roll *equals* the target's AC, it is a miss, correct? I ask because in most (if not all) D20 games that would be a hit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct, your attack roll must be higher than the target AC. If they are equal the defender gets the victory (and the attacker gets the miss). As you level up, your ability to hit a given AC will increase faster than the AC of your opponents, so as you get stronger, you will not only hit harder, but you will hit more often.

Comment: You could also add the same is true for skill vs. DC checks in Microlite20.